# finding difference between two data frames in R when they only differ in terms of frequency of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

To find the difference, I was using the sqldf package.

I have two data frames. They only differ in that the second data frame has some rows repeated multiple times as compared to the first one. That is, they both have the same values, only differ in terms of frequency.

sqldf doesn't seem to show the difference between them, since it looks like it only checks unique values. See below.

How can I overcome this? Also, is there another packages to help find difference between two frames?

```
col1 = c(1,2,3)
df1 = data.frame(col1)

col1 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
df2 = data.frame(col1)

> df1
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
> df2
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    3
7    1
8    2
9    3

sqldf('SELECT * FROM df1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM df2')
[1] col1
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
sqldf('SELECT * FROM df2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM df1')
[1] col1
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I also tried out a function as follows, but even that doesn't seem to help

```
dfdiffmyfunc <- function(x.1,x.2,...){
     x.1p <- do.call("paste", x.1)
     x.2p <- do.call("paste", x.2)
     x.1[! x.1p %in% x.2p, ]
}

> dfdiffmyfunc(df1,df2)
numeric(0)
> dfdiffmyfunc(df2,df1)
numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
f1 <- function(dat1, dat2){
      indx1 <- do.call(paste,
                transform(dat1, new=ave(col1, col1, FUN=seq_along))) 
      indx2 <- do.call(paste,
                transform(dat2, new=ave(col1, col1, FUN=seq_along)))
      dat2[!indx2 %in% indx1,, drop=FALSE] }
 f1(df1, df2)
 #  col1
 #4    1
 #5    2
 #6    3
 #7    1
 #8    2
 #9    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want this may do it:

```
sqldf("select rowid, * from df2 except select rowid, * from df1")
```

giving:

```
  rowid col1
1     4    1
2     5    2
3     6    3
4     7    1
5     8    2
6     9    3
```